# Does spring data jpa @query support projection?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, projection

spring boot version: 1.5.10, spring data jpa 1.11.10

In my MyEntityRespostory:

```
 Page<MyEntityPro> findByName(String name,Pageable pageable ) // working

 @("select e from MyEntity e")
 Page<MyEntity> search1(Pageable pageable) // working

 @("select e from MyEntity e")
 Page<MyEntityPro> search2(Pageable pageable) //error-No aliases found in result tuple! Make sure your query defines aliase
```

I searched the error and found: issue [DATAJPA-885](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1242)

Comment: Please put some efforts and provide full details while asking question. It will help others to understand the question and answer easily.

Comment: Please add the code for MyEntity and MyEntity projection and a full stacktrace of the error

Comment: This is a little strange. I comment the one-to-many and many-to-many relation in my entity, it works. Then I try to find the which relation cause the bug. It still works , when I bring all relations back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use upper query keyword, it will cause the problem.

```
....
@query("SELECT e FROM MyEntity") // bug
......
@query("select e from MyEntity") // working
...
```